# How to detect non-ascii characters in C# source code

Tags: c#

I have a really stupid but difficult problem. I'm working with some really bad C# legacy code that has many non-ASCII characters in class and method names, which causes a lot of problems when objects are serialized into strings and sent over http/tcp/...
I'm looking for a way to scan C# code and detect all non-ASCII characters in names of classes/methods/properties/enums/..., but not inside string literals or comments or anything else that is not C# code:

```
public enum Languages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// English
    /// </summary>
    English = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// Česká         <- acceptable
    /// </summary>
    Česká = 2,     // <- not acceptable
}

Logger.Info("Selectes language: Česká"); // <- acceptable
```

Any way to achive this would help: either programmatic or using any kind of tool.

***EDIT***: as many people in comments suggest I should fix the serialization instead of cleaning out non-ACII chars, I want to clarify why this is not an option here. Some class/method names have ASCII and non-ASCII chars mixed in them. For example, `MyСlass` looks like a perfecly valid English name, but in reality it has a Russian letter `С` in the middle, which is clearly a mistake made a developer who forgot to change their input language. I want to get rid of such errors in code.

Comment: You can use roslyn to analyze the code and check for symbol names with non-ASCII characters. Or you can use a quick&dirty regex search in VS to match non-ASCII excluding anything inside double quotes. That won't work with escaped quotes in strings, but will could give you some results immediatelly

Comment: Nothing you can't do with simple reflection, start with Assembly.GetTypes().  But jeez marie, what a sledgehammer solution to a simple encoding bug.  Fix the bug.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012+ uses the same regex syntax as .NET. This means that you can specify [Unicode ranges and classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3), eg `\p{IsBasicLatin}+`

Comment: `String`s can be very complex, e.g. `$@"Some string with invalid ({Česká}) chars"`; that's why in general case I can't see any reasonable alternative to parser (Roslyn).

Comment: @DmitryBychenko once you replace `Languages.Česká` with `Languages.Czech` you can find interpolation cases with a compilation. The problem is finding the *symbols* in the first place, without spending a lot of time

Comment: @AndreBorges I agree with Hans Passant that serialization is **NOT** a good reason to change names. .NET's built-in mechanisms don't care about ASCII or Unicode because *every* string is Unicode. You have to do extra work to create codepage bugs in .NET. Changing `Česká` for `Czech` to make the code more readable, I can understand. For serialization, not at all

Comment: @HansPassant, PanagiotisKanavos, please see my edits

Comment: Seems like two problems; perhaps you should fix them both. (It's sad when code utterly fails to handle such well-defined things as the allowable characters in .NET type names.) You could handle the second problem with a code inspector that uses a spell checker—but you might have to commit to a lot more work to fix all spelling errors in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by someone, you could write an Analyzer to check naming of classes/methods/...

I was curious about writing an analyzer, so I wrote it. It requires VS 2015/2017

You'll need the .NET Compiler Platform SDK. So...

- New Project, Models, Visual C#, Extensibility, With .NET 4.6.2 (check the combo box in the top part of the window), Analyzer with Code Fix

If you can't find it, then download it from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.NETCompilerPlatformSDK .

Then replace the content of DiagnosticAnalyzer.cs with:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace NonAsciiAnalyzer
{
    [DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
    public class NonAsciiAnalyzerAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
    {
        public const string DiagnosticId = "NonAsciiAnalyzer";

        // You can change these strings in the Resources.resx file. If you do not want your analyzer to be localize-able, you can use regular strings for Title and MessageFormat.
        // See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/analyzers/Localizing%20Analyzers.md for more on localization
        private static readonly LocalizableString Title = new LocalizableResourceString(nameof(Resources.AnalyzerTitle), Resources.ResourceManager, typeof(Resources));
        private static readonly LocalizableString MessageFormat = new LocalizableResourceString(nameof(Resources.AnalyzerMessageFormat), Resources.ResourceManager, typeof(Resources));
        private static readonly LocalizableString Description = new LocalizableResourceString(nameof(Resources.AnalyzerDescription), Resources.ResourceManager, typeof(Resources));
        private const string Category = "Naming";

        private static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);

        public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics { get { return ImmutableArray.Create(Rule); } }

        public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
        {
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNamespaceDeclaration, SyntaxKind.NamespaceDeclaration);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeInterfaceDeclaration, SyntaxKind.InterfaceDeclaration);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeClassDeclaration, SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeStructDeclaration, SyntaxKind.StructDeclaration);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeDelegateDeclaration, SyntaxKind.DelegateDeclaration);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeEnumDeclaration, SyntaxKind.EnumDeclaration);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeEnumMemberDeclaration, SyntaxKind.EnumMemberDeclaration);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeFieldDeclaration, SyntaxKind.FieldDeclaration);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeEventDeclaration, SyntaxKind.EventDeclaration);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzePropertyDeclaration, SyntaxKind.PropertyDeclaration);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeMethodDeclaration, SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration);

            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeUsingDirective, SyntaxKind.UsingDirective);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeExternAliasDirective, SyntaxKind.ExternAliasDirective);

            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeTypeParameter, SyntaxKind.TypeParameter);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeParameter, SyntaxKind.Parameter);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeVariableDeclaration, SyntaxKind.VariableDeclaration);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeLabelStatement, SyntaxKind.LabeledStatement);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeCatchDeclaration, SyntaxKind.CatchDeclaration);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeForEachStatement, SyntaxKind.ForEachStatement);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeAnonymousObjectMemberDeclarator, SyntaxKind.AnonymousObjectMemberDeclarator);

            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeFromClause, SyntaxKind.FromClause);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeLetClause, SyntaxKind.LetClause);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeJoinClause, SyntaxKind.JoinClause);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeJoinIntoClause, SyntaxKind.JoinIntoClause);
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeQueryContinuation, SyntaxKind.QueryContinuation);
        }

        private void AnalyzeNamespaceDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var nds = (NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
            var sns = (SimpleNameSyntax)nds.Name;
            string name = sns.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Namespace: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeInterfaceDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var ids = (InterfaceDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = ids.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Interface: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeClassDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var cds = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = cds.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Class: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeStructDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var sds = (StructDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = sds.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Struct: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeDelegateDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var dds = (DelegateDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = dds.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Delegate: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeEnumDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var eds = (EnumDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = eds.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Enum: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeEnumMemberDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var emds = (EnumMemberDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = emds.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Enum Member: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        // Already done by LocalDeclaration
        private void AnalyzeFieldDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            //var fds = (FieldDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;

            //foreach (var fds2 in fds.Declaration.Variables)
            //{
            //    string name = fds2.Identifier.Text;
            //    Debug.WriteLine("Field: " + name);
            //    Check(context, name, Rule);
            //}
        }

        private void AnalyzeEventDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var eds = (EventDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = eds.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Event: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzePropertyDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var pds = (PropertyDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = pds.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Property: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeMethodDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var mds = (MethodDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = mds.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Method: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeUsingDirective(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var uds = (UsingDirectiveSyntax)context.Node;

            if (uds.Alias == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            string name = uds.Alias.Name.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Using Alias: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeExternAliasDirective(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var eads = (ExternAliasDirectiveSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = eads.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Extern Alias: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeTypeParameter(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var tps = (TypeParameterSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = tps.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Type Parameter: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeParameter(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var ps = (ParameterSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = ps.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Parameter: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        // Fields/const fields/local variables/local functions
        private void AnalyzeVariableDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var vds = (VariableDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;

            foreach (var vds2 in vds.Variables)
            {
                string name = vds2.Identifier.Text;
                Debug.WriteLine("Local: " + name);
                Check(context, name, Rule);
            }
        }

        private void AnalyzeLabelStatement(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var lss = (LabeledStatementSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = lss.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Label: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeCatchDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var cds = (CatchDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = cds.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Catch Variable: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeForEachStatement(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var fess = (ForEachStatementSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = fess.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("ForEach Variable: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeAnonymousObjectMemberDeclarator(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var aqns = (AnonymousObjectMemberDeclaratorSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = aqns.NameEquals.Name.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Anonymous Field: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeFromClause(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var fcs = (FromClauseSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = fcs.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("From: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeLetClause(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var lcs = (LetClauseSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = lcs.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Let: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeJoinClause(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var jcs = (JoinClauseSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = jcs.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Join: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeJoinIntoClause(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var jics = (JoinIntoClauseSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = jics.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Join Into: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void AnalyzeQueryContinuation(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var qcs = (QueryContinuationSyntax)context.Node;
            string name = qcs.Identifier.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("Into: " + name);
            Check(context, name, Rule);
        }

        private void Check(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context, string name, DiagnosticDescriptor rule)
        {
            // .NET Core, with full .NET no .ToCharArray()
            if (name.ToCharArray().Any(x => x > 0x7f))
            {
                // For all such symbols, produce a diagnostic.
                var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(rule, context.Node.GetLocation(), name);
                context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I was curious about how to check the name local variables, parameters, ..., so in the end I'm checking nearly everything (surely I forgot something... Sadly there is no unified "get me all the name of user defined "things"")... And `RegisterSymbolAction` only return top-level symbols (no local functions for example).